# Message size with defined constants

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all. Was just wondering if [message enum constants](http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg#Constants) get included in the message size. For example, if I have a message that has a uint8 constant defined to be 1 and then the actual uint8 payload, would the message take up 8 bits or 16 bits?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327925/message-size-with-defined-constants/) by [jwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/38683/jwin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2019-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two sides to this:

1. serialisation of actual message contents to the `stream` (in `ros::serialization::Serializer<>::*(..)`), and
2. message structure definition exchanged by nodes when a connection is setup (ie: msg, srv or action connections)

For the first: no, constants do not get serialised, only message fields. See here for an example of the `DiagnosticsStatus.msg` code (from `/opt/ros/melodic/include/diagnostic_msgs/DiagnosticStatus.h`, slightly simplified):

```
namespace serialization
{
  template<..> struct Serializer<..>
  {
    template<..> inline static void allInOne(Stream& stream, T m)
    {
      stream.next(m.level);
      stream.next(m.name);
      stream.next(m.message);
      stream.next(m.hardware_id);
      stream.next(m.values);
    }
  };
}
```

Legal values for `level` in this case would be one of the values defined by the constants in the message definition (`OK`, `WARN`, `ERROR` or `STALE`), but only `level` gets serialised.

As for the second: upon subscribing, nodes will negotiate the parameters/configuration of the actual TCP or UDP connection that will be used to exchange message data (ie: the bytes serialised into the `stream` in the code shown above, which in the end is a buffer). In that negotation, the complete message definition is exchanged as well and that message definition does contain the constants (see [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Connection%20Header) for `TCPROS`). So in this case, they are included.

Negotation takes place only once per connection, so the message definition is exchanged only once as well.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jwin](https://answers.ros.org/users/38683/jwin/) on 2019-07-09**:
Ah I see that's perfect then since the network bandwidth will only consist of the actual payload (except for the initial negotiation setup). Thank you and great answer as always.